# Retrieve unique data from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique, distinct

I have a table in my database which contains 5 rows. I am trying to write an sql statement that will retrieve all rows which only have 1 agency assigned to them.

```
case_id    agency_ID
   1          4
   2          4
   3          3
   4          2
   4          4
```

To clarify I would like to select the required rows (and any further rows) but only if the case_id is unique. Any rows with duplicates would be ommited.

I have tried to use DISTINCT(case_id), COUNT(*) to count all rows but it doesn't work and it's slowly sapping away my soul. It is probably an easy fix, but for the life of me I just can't see it.

Hope this is enough information to go on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table GROUP BY case_id HAVING COUNT(agency_ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT case_id,agency_ID,COUNT(case_id) as c 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY case_id
HAVING (c=1)
```

Comment: Hanky Panky you hero, that worked perfectly. Is there anyway I can extend the statement to show one row with an overall count total of the unique rows?